# Create contenteditable divs on keypress enter with AngularJs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, contenteditable

How to create a contenteditable div which can be binded with keypress enter and create other contenteditable divs, these newly created divs will have the same functionality as the first one i.e. produce new divs which are also contenteditable when keypressed is enter.

I am not trying to create nested divs. Please help I am new to Angular

Comment: Please make an attempt first. Look at https://docs.angularjs.org/api